# 500 errors for images used by Perl CGI application

Tags: perl, apache, cgi, foswiki

I've installed [Foswiki](http://foswiki.org/) but I've problem when my app try load images. The images don't load...

I've get a solution but I'm not sure if is correct ...

This is my configuration for CGI directory

```
#
# "C:/Archivos de programa/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "C:/Archivos de programa/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI 
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    AddHandler default-handler .jpg .png .gif .js .txt .bat .css 
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have to add the extensions one by one :(...

Comment: This isn't a Perl question or a programming question. But the answer is: you're not supposed to put images or CSS (or any kind of files) in the `cgi-bin` directory; only executable programs.

Comment: "doesn't load" - what *does* happen?  does the request get to the server?  what status or content is returned in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going out on a bit of a limb here, but I'm guessing that, in addition to the configuration included in your question, this directory is also the target of a `ScriptAlias` directive (probably for `/cgi-bin`, and possibly in the default Apache configuration rather than in something you've explicitly done).  `ScriptAlias` says that every file in the directory is a CGI script; see [the directive documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias).  That's why you have to override that behavior with `AddHandler`.

If you want to control which files are executed as CGI scripts using `AddHandler` with file extensions like `.cgi`, don't use `ScriptAlias`.  Without `ScriptAlias`, the default will be to serve the file out as a resource unless you explicitly say to execute it as a CGI script.